# Use localPosition and localRotation of a child to align parent (Unity, QR-Codes)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, alignment, parent

I'm using an editor to spread QR-Codes in local space of an object. For better understanding, I'll try to explain it with an example:

First I load a model of a car into the editor. This model is our parent. Now I place a QR-Code on each side mirror of the car. The localPosition and localRotation of these QR-Codes are saved for later reference in my application. I also place a 3D-Model in the center of the hood of the car. This 3D-Model will be shown in my AR-Application.

Now I'm using this application inside a real car (prefably the model, I used as reference in my editor). I placed QR-Codes on the real side mirrors of this car. Now when my application detects one of the QR-Codes, I want to use the localPosition and localRotation that I stored earlier, to align the parent in real life.

I'm using this code, to align the parent:

```
        public class StickyParent : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] Transform parent;
        [SerializeField] Transform qrCode;
     
        [SerializeField] Vector3 localQrPosition;
        [SerializeField] Vector3 localQrRotation;
     
        public void Align()
        {
            if (parent == null) return;
     
           var fixedPos = new Vector3(-localQrPosition.x, -localQrPosition.y, localQrPosition.z); // Had to invert x and y, for the correct outcome. Not sure why...
            var trackedPosition = qrCode.TransformPointUnscaled(fixedPos); // Extention method: TransformPoint that ignores scale
            var trackedRotation = qrCode.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(localQrRotation);
     
            parent.position = trackedPosition;
            parent.rotation = trackedRotation;
        }
    }
```

This code seems do the right thing, but the calculations are definetly wrong. Maybe someone understands this issue and can tell me the correct math, to align a parent based on pre-stored localPos and localRot of a child.

Comment: Trying to confirm if I understand correctly: `localQrPosition` and `localQrRotation` are values you configure in the Inspector and are the positions where the `qrCode` should be placed relative to `parent`, right? Then when you scan the code the object `qrCode` is placed to it (in worldspace) and now you try to move `parent` accordingly thus that it again ends up in the correct position so that `qrCode` would again be placed correctly relative to it ... is this about right?

Comment: why do you apply `parent.position` in absolute world space but `parent.localRotation` in local space?

Comment: localQrPosition and localQrRotation are constants from a json file. For testing, I'm just simulating this in the inspector, thats why they are [SerializeField]. Parent is Root, so localPosition is equal to position. A scanned QR-Code will also be in Root. The plan is to use the QRs position and add the pre-stored localQrPos and localQrRotation as an offset, to alingn the "Parent"

Answer (score 1):

I think if I understood correctly what you have is

- `localQrPosition` and `localQrRotation` are values you configure in the Inspector and are the positions where the `qrCode` should be placed relative to `parent`
- When you scan the code the object `qrCode` is placed to it (in worldspace)
- now you try to move `parent` accordingly thus that it again ends up in the correct position so that `qrCode` would again be placed correctly relative to it

However, if I read the code correctly what you have in `localQrPosition` and `localQrRotation` is the transforms of the **QR code** relative to the **parent**, but your code seems to treat them the other way round and you are trying to use them as the transforms of the **parent** relative to the **QR code**.

I would probably do something like the following

First some extensions - honestly don't know why these still don't exist ;)

```
public static class TransfomExtensions
{
    ///<summary>Converts worlsRotation into local space rotation relative to this transform</summary>
    public static Quaternion InverseTransformRotation(this Transform transform, Quaternion worldRotation)
    {
        return Quaternion.Inverse(transform.rotation) * worldRotation;
    }

    ///<summary>Converts localRotation from local space relative to this transform into absolute world rotation</summary>
    public static Quaternion TransformRotation(this Transform transform, Quaternion localRotation)
    {
        return transform.rotation * localRotation;
    }
}
```

And then in your component - I would attach it to the according qrCode and actually simply place the QRCode correctly in your Unity scene

```
public class StickyParent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform parent;

    // as said I would rather place this directly on according qrCode object 
    // which would make this redunant
    //[SerializeField] private Transform qrCode;

    [SerializeField] private Vector3 relativePosition;
    [SerializeField] private Quaternion relativeRotation;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // via the content menu of this component simply pre-store the relative values
    [ContextMenu(nameof(UpdateRelativeValues))]
    private void UpdateRelativeValues()
    {
        // store the PARENT's transform relative to the QRCODE!
        // this might seem unintuitive at first as this is the opposite of how the hierarchy looks like
        // but it doesn't really matter. What we want to do later is place the parent relative to the QR code so that's what we store
        relativePosition = transform.InverseTranformPoint(parent.position);
        relativeRotation = transform.InverseTransformRotation(parent.rotation);

        UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
    }
#endif

    public void Align()
    {
        // as the child object would also be transformed along
        // if the parent is moved/rotated store and afterwards re-assign the transforms 
        var pos = transform.position;
        var rot = transform.rotation;

        // and then simply apply back both relative to the scanned QRCode
        parent.position = transform.TransformPoint(relativePosition);
        parent.rotation = transform.TransformRotation(relativeRotation);

        // finally reassign to confirm that the virtual QR code again matches with the real one
        // and the car is now correctly placed relative to it
        transform.position = pos;
        transform.rotation = rot;
    }
}
```

---

If you really have to stick to the other way round and the only inpu you have is

```
Vector3 localQrPosition;
Vector3 localQrRotation;
```

as relative to the parent, then we will have to do some assumptions - from your comment we now know that both `parent` and `qrcode` are on scene root level which helps a lot since it allows to simply to all calculcations in **world space**!

In that case I think you still basically need to invert your values and do something like

```
var localQrRot = Quaternion.Euler(localQrRotation);
// creates an inverted rotation basically so that
// rotation * invertedRotation = Quaternion.identity
var invertedLocalQrRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(localQrRot);
// basically take the tracked qr rotation and rotate back about the stored offset
var parentRotation = qrcode.rotation * invertedLocalQrRotation;
parent.rotation = parentRotation;
// then use that same orientation space to also apply the positional offset
// also this offset needs to be inverted accordingly 
parent.position = qrcode.position - parentRotation * localQrPosition;
```

Comment: We don't need to place the QR-Code here. I just need to place the parent at the relative offsetPos of the tracked QR-Code. Now another issue is here, that this editor does not support Quaternions. So I must use eulerAngles for the offsetRotation. I hope they behave the same, using your extention. Thank's I'll try it.

Comment: @KarlSupertramp at the bottom I also added what I think should work with the values you are given (qr code relative to car) ... basically you still need to invert them all in order to calculate the other way round car transforms relative to qr code

Comment: I tried this. It basicly has the same outcome. Rotation is not being applied as expected. The weird part here is, that localQrRotation.y and localQrRotation.z rotate the parent around the same axis. y rotates clockwise around z and z rotates counter-clockwise around z

Comment: @KarlSupertramp hm sorry, unfortunately Quaternions is really not one of my strengths ^^ it sounds a bit like a gimbal lock issue you are getting

Comment: I'll try to set to the QrCodes as child and use them as fixed anchor. Thanks for the help :)